# w32tm /query /configuration equivalent in 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntp

I'm trying to figure out the NTP server in use, so I issued

`w32tm /query /configuration`

But that doesn't work,

Looks like /configuration is invalid in 2003, what's a possible substitute?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows 2003 and 2003 R2 versions of w32tm.exe do not have the `/query` parameter.

If the computer in question happens to be a domain controller, an acceptable substitute might be `w32tm /monitor`. It will query every domain controller (if you're in an AD domain,) and for each computer listed, the `RefID:` is that computer's current time source. Works in 2003.

Secondly, you might get the desired results from `net time /querysntp`, but that command only works on computers who are statically configured to use a specific NTP server, not Active Directory-integrated time service. (And also doesn't work on newer versions that do have the `w32tm /query` command.)

Lastly, if neither of the above work, your last recourse is probably to either look for the last Information Event ID 37 from W32Time in the System log, or use netstat.exe and see who are talking to on UDP port 123.